# Row was not copied from the Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

The row was not copied in Treeview, I made popup copy after I pressed in row and made copy and pasted in anywhere not pasted

The code

```
        popup = tk.Menu(tree_opportunity, tearoff=0)
        def row_copy():
            item = tree_opportunity.selection()[0]
            opportunity_frame.clipboard_clear()
            opportunity_frame.clipboard_append(tree_opportunity.item(item, 
            option='text'))
            
        popup.add_command(command=row_copy,label="Copy")
        def popup_menu(event):
            tree_opportunity.identify_row(event.y)
            popup.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        
        tree_opportunity.bind('<Button-3>', popup_menu)
```

Comment: If there is no item selected, clicking the treeview with mouse *button 3* (right button) does not select any item in the treeview.  So after you select `Copy` command in the popup menu, there will be exception on the line `item = tree_opportunity.selection()[0]`.

Comment: better create minimal working example which we could copy and run to see problem and test solutions.

Comment: I have tested your code and I can copy the content of `text` option of *the selected item* in `tree_opportunity` to clipboard which I can paste into another application like `notepad`.

Comment: Not working with me. I think the issue is with selecting the item inside the code. if I printed item, it printed 1001.

Comment: `print(item)` gives `I001` means that the first item is selected.  BTW how do you insert records into the treeview? Did you assign the `text` option when inserting records? Your code copies the content of `text` option of the selected item into the clipboard.