# Not copying from Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

The row was not copied in Treeview, I made popup copy after I pressed in row and made copy and pasted in anywhere not pasted

The code

```
    popup = tk.Menu(tree_opportunity, tearoff=0)
    def row_copy():
        item = tree_opportunity.selection()[0]
        opportunity_frame.clipboard_clear()
        opportunity_frame.clipboard_append(tree_opportunity.item(item, 
        option='text'))
        
    popup.add_command(command=row_copy,label="Copy")
    def popup_menu(event):
        tree_opportunity.identify_row(event.y)
        popup.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    
    tree_opportunity.bind('<Button-3>', popup_menu)
```

Comment: Don't ask same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378502/row-was-not-copied-from-the-treeview) twice.

Comment: I haven't found a solution to the question yet

Comment: maybe first use `print()`, `print(type())` to see what you have in variables. Maybe it can't be copied to clipboard